# Aligning instances to curve normal in Geometry nodes

Tags: blender

I'm trying to find a way to create a way to instance geometry along points on a curve in Blender geometry nodes. I want the X or Y axis of the instances to be perpendicular to the original curve at all points.

I have no problem using Curve to Points to instantiate, but I can't find a way to align the objects to the tangent of the original curve I'm using. Using the rotation parameter from Curve to Points works, but that gives the wrong direction of points that are close to the corners of the original curve.

[image: Screenshot of node tree]

Subdividing the curve and using align euler to vector gives the same problem - points at the corners has an averaged tangent that does not make them perpendicular to the original curve.  I tried removing the corner points of the original points using an geometry proximity nodes, but that doesn't seem to help. I'm thinking that I should use the geometry proximity node in another way, but I can't wrap my head around it.